# Gallery autorotation on

Tags: javascript

```
var position = 0;
var size = 0;
var id = 0;

function init(){
  var slides = document.getElementById("gallery").children;
  var button = document.getElementById('btn');
  var size = slides.length;

for(var i = 1; i<size; i++){
    slides[i].style.display = 'none';

}
   function slide(){
     if (position < size){
     slides[position].style.display = "block";      
     position++;
 }
 else{
    position = 0;
    for(var i=1; i<size; ++i){
        slides[i].style.display = "none";

    }
  }

} 

button.onclick =function(){
    if (button.innerHTML == "PLAY") {
        id = setInterval(slide, 500);
        button.innerHTML = "STOP";
    }
    else {
        button.innerHTML = "PLAY";
        clearTimeout(id);
    }
  };

 }

init();
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/khimanand_oli/ytc4LeLc/3/

above is the fiddle link,
Gallery should switches slides in autorotation, or visual interval of autoration  on every 0.5 second,
but currently there is more time gap when the gallery restart slides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in your slide function, when position is equal to size, you reset the list and nothing more. Just go trough it.

1. Display the image (last image in list)
2. wait 0.5 seconds
3. reset list (does display the first image)
4. wait 0.5 seconds
5. display the first image again

so before you go to the second image you waited 1 second. Just make it so that when the slider resets it displays the first image and sets the position to the second image so that in the next interval you display the second

I would remake your function like this

```
//function of slider
function slide(){
    slides[position].style.display = "none";

    if(position < size - 1){
        position++;
    }
    else{
        position = 0;
    }
    slides[position].style.display = "block";
}
```

With this you don't have all images displayed at the same time, and the position variable is always the number of the image that is being displayed at the moment, which can be helpfull for further functions

Comment: Please suggest with answer so that every image should rotate on 0.5sec interval, I am learning JS. how could I do that.

Comment: I have added a example